# Creepage distance over pcb

Tags: pcb, clearance, ul, creepage

How to measure creepage distance over pcb ?
Is creepage and clearance distance measure by pbc layout or soldering?

Comment: If your soldering does not closely follow your PCB layout, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Pcb layout with masking are not taken into account to measuring creepage distance

Comment: Is creepage distance measure from solder point or end of pcb layout with masking

Comment: creepage is dielectric contamination and air is much better than surface gap   read more  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=creepage  elsewhere there are safety standards for levels of contamination RH+dust + salt spray if applicable.

Answer (score 3):

> How to measure creepage distance over pcb ? Is creepage and clearance
>   distance measure by pbc layout or soldering?

This might help: -

[image]

Picture from [this](https://forum.mysensors.org/topic/4175/clearance-creepage-and-other-safety-aspects-in-mysensors-pcbs) site.

Comment: But how to measure creepage distance between primary pin to secondary pin of transform at pcb when any another conductive surface or component comes on the way of creepage distance

Comment: If the "thing" coming in the way cannot be relied upon for its insulation properties then it should be regarded as a conductor. If it can be *somewhat" regarded as an insulator under normal conditions then you might be able to regard it as equivalent to air, else regard it as a conductor. Safety first.

Comment: If conductor is on way of creepage distance and how to measure?? Is measured first A point to conductor then skip creepage distance of conductor then to the final B point as  regards A +B distance for creepage

Comment: The width of the conductor would be regarded as zero unless it was a suitable earth conductor then it would negate the need to determine the full creapage path. But otherwise, skip the conductor width.

Comment: You mean yo say just add point A to conductor and skip conductor width and B from second end point as A+B distance without conductor width.

Comment: For simple isolated non-insulating materials along the path between A and B, yes.

Comment: Creepage is measured by the dielectric withstanding voltage in  best case or nominal or worst case conditions to create standards for different environmental ratings for different applications. This is done routinely from professionals in high value products but more often only clean new and so overlooked from contaminant growth especially with fans. HIPOT is a slow ramped voltage but also something like 1/10us transient HVAC pulse tests are done at higher levels in safety stds.

Comment: But in case of conductor between A and B point

Comment: A conductor is a non-insulating material.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. Is this case mentioned in iec 60950-1 or another standard. If you want suggest me any standard to read creepage clearance distance plz suggest

Comment: It is you who must choose the standard that applies to the equipment concerned. As far as I'm aware they all have the same way of defining creapage and clearance as per your question.

Comment: If a want to measure creepage distance over pcb between transform primary to secondary pins but between them some conductive components comes in way then how do i measure creepage distance? By negating conductive component or measuring distance between conductive components.

Comment: Any non-earthed conducting part is regarded as having zero length i.e. the creepage distance (without the conductive material) is reduced by the relevant dimension of the conducting material.

Answer (score 1):

**[Creepage](https://www.google.com/search?q=Creepage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)** occurs from excited ion flow in an insulator between charges and conductors with a voltage potential difference.  Excess solder flux may be an issue if excessive in the gap but that would be abnormal. Imagine it as a sticky collector of dust. This is why boards are kept clean and dry with suitable air gaps where needed when AC grid potential power is behind these voltages.

---

Other  relevant info, to put things into perspective.

---

Partial Discharges could be like the dust in the air with vast distances in km from cloud to earth or nm in semiconductor lithography where contamination is limited by clean room technology yet ESD is still a threat to 12nm epitaxial gaps or the ribbed insulators in transmission towers which use HV bushings surface creepage is measured in kV/mm for the surface path length which is increased the air gaps in each ringed rib but then cleansed by rain yet also bridged by the water's capacitance.

> But in this case, you are referring to **PCB surface creepage**. It would be measured by a HIPOT but is **significantly** 10%to90% (worst case) degraded by gross contamination with dust accumulated by fans and humidity. This is why an air gap is preferred.  A streamer arc is followed by an arc when HIPOT fails so the tester ought to be currently limited with for example 3 to 4kVdc and 1M to 10M resistance in series with the probe to prevent capacitance discharge.  E-field gradients are increased with sharp points on the conductors which lower the breakdown withstanding voltage from power surges such as inductive lightning surges.

It  may be measured in giga or mega ohms but what really happens is once charge flow starts, it accelerates the resistance drops and capacitance rises until the medium has a weak link and discharges. If this bridges the entire gap then it becomes an avalanche diode like arc with all the follow-on current available.  Electrical RTV Silicone is often used around high voltage triplers to reduce surface creepage for example.  SParkplug wires are made of long rubber  insulation for better protection from dust accumulation. Some parts are usually protected from dust to create better creepage barrier such as the housing for the inductive coils.